# PHP+BillDesk payment gateway integration issue

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate BillDesk payment gateway with my PHP website. I am getting this below error when I run my simple PHP code

**{"status":422,"error_type":"invalid_data_error","error_code":"GNIDE0004","message":"Invalid Content-type header"}**

Here is my PHP code. Please note this is only for testing purpose

```
<?php
$str = "<MerchantId>|order45608988|NA|300.00|NA|NA|NA|INR|NA|TypeField1|<ClientID>|NA|NA|TypeField2|Txtadditionalinfo1|Txtadditionalinfo2|http://google.com";

$checksum = hash_hmac('sha256',$str,"<secretkey>", false); 
$checksum_value = strtoupper($checksum);


echo '<form action="https://pguat.billdesk.io/payments/ve1_2/orders/create" method="post" id="billdesk_payment_form">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="MerchantId" value="<MerchantId>"/>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="CurrencyType" value="INR"/>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="SecurityId" value="<ClientID>"/>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="txtCustomerID" value="order45608988" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="txtTxnAmount" value="300.00" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="txtAdditionalInfo1″ value="" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="RU" value="http://returnURL.com" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="CheckSumKey" value="<secretkey>"/>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="CheckSum" value="'.$checksum_value.'"/>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="msg" value="'.$str.'" />';
echo '</form>';

echo '<script>document.getElementById("billdesk_payment_form").submit();</script>';
?>
```

I have referenced the BillDesk docs and I am not getting exactly what changes I have to do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you test what happens if add `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` attribute to the form tag?

Comment: @Lessmore : Yeah I tried that but same issue it shows

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Billdesk has changed payment gateway. sample as given below */

/****
 config.php
*****/

    $MerchantID = "ABCDEF01";
    $ClientID = "abcdef01";
    $responseurl = "https://www.merchantwebsite.com/ru.php";
    $secretkey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $returnURL = "https://www.merchantwebsite.com/paymentresponse.php";
    $billdesk_URL = "https://pguat.billdesk.io/payments/ve1_2/orders/create";
        
/****
 process.php
*****/

    use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

    /*****************************************/
        // Build headers
    /*****************************************/
    
    $headers = ["alg" => "HS256", "clientid" => $ClientID, "kid" => "HMAC"];

    $payload = [
      "mercid" => $MerchantID,
      "orderid" => $transaction_id,
      "amount" => $totalamount,
      "order_date" => $date_atom,
      "currency" => "356",
      "ru" => $responseurl,
      "additional_info" => [
        "additional_info1" => $CustomerID,
        "additional_info2" => $PaymentFor,
        "additional_info3" => "NA",
        "additional_info4" => "NA",
        "additional_info5" => "NA",
        "additional_info6" => "NA",
        "additional_info7" => "NA",
      ],
      "itemcode" => "DIRECT",
      "device" => [
        "init_channel" => "internet",
        "ip" => $ipaddress,
        "mac" => $macaddress,
        "imei" => $imei,
        "accept_header" => "text/html",
        "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0",
        "fingerprintid" => $fingerprintid
      ]
    ];
    
    

    /*****************************************/
        // Encode payload
    /*****************************************/

    $curl_payload = JWT::encode($payload, $secretkey, "HS256", null ,$headers);
    
    /*****************************************/
        // Submit to Billdesk
    /*****************************************/
    $ch = curl_init( $billdesk_URL );
    $ch_headers = array(
        "Content-Type: application/jose",
        "accept: application/jose",
        "BD-Traceid: $transaction_id",
        "BD-Timestamp: $servertimeYYYYMMddHHmmss"
    );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $ch_headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_payload);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                        
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    /*****************************************/
        // Billdesk Response
    /*****************************************/
    
    $launch_billdesk = false;
    try { 
        $result_decoded = JWT::decode($result, $secretkey, array('HS256'));
        $result_array = (array) $result_decoded;
            
        if ($result_decoded->status == 'ACTIVE') {
            $transactionid = $result_array['links'][1]->parameters->bdorderid;
            $authtoken = $result_array['links'][1]->headers->authorization;

            $launch_billdesk = true;   //write js code to launch sdk

        } else { // Response error
            echo "Response error";
        }
                        
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "<br><br>Return signature validation FAILED: $e";
    }
    
    
/****
 paymentresponse.php
*****/

    use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
        
    /*****************************************/
        // Read POST data
    /*****************************************/ 
    $tx = "";
    if(!empty($_POST)) { 
        $tx_array = $_POST;
        if (isset($tx_array['transaction_response'])) {
            $tx = $tx_array['transaction_response'];
        }
    } else {
        echo "<br><br>Invalid call<br>";
        die();
    }
    
    
    /*****************************************/
        // Signature validation
    /*****************************************/ 
    try { 
        $result_decoded = JWT::decode($tx, $secretkey, array('HS256'));
        $result_array = (array) $result_decoded;
        $result_json =  json_encode($result_array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);       
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //echo $e; 
        echo "<br><br>Invalid response<br>";
        die();
    }
    
    /*****************************************/
        // Process info
    /*****************************************/ 
    if ($result_decoded->transaction_error_type == 'success') {
        
        $orderid = $result_decoded->orderid;
        $transaction_date = $result_decoded->transaction_date;
        $transactionid = $result_decoded->transactionid;    //payment transaction id
        $charge_amount = $result_decoded->charge_amount;

        /*  SAVE TO DB and send receipt     */
        $success = updateTransactionToDB($result_array);        
        GenerateReceiptEmail($orderid, 1, $draftreceipt);
        
        echo "<h2>Transaction was successful....</h2>";
        echo "Transaction Date: $transaction_date<br>";
        echo "Transaction ID: $transactionid<br>";
        echo "Charge Amount: ₹$charge_amount<br>";          


    } else { // Error
        $txerror = $result_decoded->transaction_error_type;
        $txid = $result_decoded->transactionid;
        echo "<h2>Transaction FAILED....</h2>";
        echo "Transaction Date: $transaction_date<br>";
        echo "Transaction ID: $transactionid<br>";
        echo "Charge Amount: ₹$charge_amount<br>";          
        echo "Failure Reason: ₹$transaction_error_desc<br>";            
    }
```

Comment: Billdesk has changed payment gateway. sample as given below

Comment: I am getting this error window.loadBillDeskSdk is not a function in js sdk and it is not loading. Do you know why it is not working?